# Rails, model method returning array instead of iterating over the results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

new ruby on rails user here. I have a question about the following few lines of code.

First example in view.

```
<% sailing.travelling_parties.each do |party| %>
  <% party.party_registers.each do |reg| %>
    <%= reg.user.detailed_user.first_name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

When I run it in the in view, i get my expected result which is multiple names printed out. When I move it to the model and change it to the following,

Second example, in model. The ** represents what I'm actually trying to accomplish in this entire example.

```
class Sailing < ActiveRecord::Base

...

def gather_data
 self.travelling_parties.each do |party|
  party.party_registers.each do |reg|
    reg.user.detailed_user.first_name
    ** use a variable to count loop iterations **
  end
 end
end
```

Second example, in View

```
<%= sailing.gather_data %>
```

This is printing out an array filled with the 'travelling_parties' I am trying to iterate over, not what I had expected at all! So, obviously it only loops once regardless of how many names are in the sailing record.

Can any shed any light on why this is happening, and how I can get it to work like the first example, without actually putting my business logic in the view?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map), which transforms array into other array according to given block:

```
def gather_data
  travelling_parties.map do |party|
    party.party_registers.map do |reg|
      reg.user.detailed_user.first_name
    end
  end
end
```

This method returns array of arrays with first names. If you want get one-dimensional array, use `flat_map` instead of first `map`, like below:

```
def gather_data
  travelling_parties.flat_map do |party|
    party.party_registers.map do |reg|
      reg.user.detailed_user.first_name
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Great! This is what I was looking for, thanks. Do you know know I would be able to get my array of names, AND get the count of names without having to call   <p><%= sailing.gather_data.count %></p> AND <p><%= sailing.gather_data %></p> (basically doubling my query. Thanks again!

Comment: @Aptorian, put `sailing.gather_data` into variable and use `size` instead of `count` on this variable